# linux awk command in ansible looping

Tags: linux, awk, ansible

i am a beginner in using awk. Using ansible, i want to print the received output of ping command then write it to file. pings are done from hosts 10.0.0.3 and 10.0.0.6 to 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.0.2, respectively. The following is ansible task that I have:

```
- name: CHECK PING
  shell: ping {{ item[0] }} -c 2 -s {{ item[1] }} | grep -i received | awk '{print "{{item[1]}} :\n"," {{item[0]}} :", $4}'
  register: p
  with_nested:
  - [ '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2' ]
  - [ '10.0.0.3', '10.0.0.6' ]

- copy:
    content: "{{ p.results | map(attribute='stdout') | join('\n')}}"
    dest: ping.txt
```

keep in mind that item[1] is the ping source (10.0.0.3 and 10.0.0.6) and the item[0] is the ping destination. the following is the contents of ping.txt

```
10.0.0.3 :
   10.0.0.1 : 2
10.0.0.6 :
   10.0.0.1 : 2
10.0.0.3 :
   10.0.0.2 : 0
10.0.0.6 :
   10.0.0.2 : 0
```

even though the output is correct, I don't want a double "key", so the output I want is:

```
10.0.0.3 :
   10.0.0.1 : 2
   10.0.0.2 : 0
10.0.0.6 :
   10.0.0.1 : 2
   10.0.0.2 : 0
```

(i.e. concatenate data 10.0.0.3 and 10.0.0.6 so that their "key" is not double). what changes to the script need to be made to get this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure *awk* to print valid YAML

```yaml
    p:
      results:
        - stdout: '{10.0.0.3: {10.0.0.1: 2}}'
        - stdout: '{10.0.0.6: {10.0.0.1: 2}}'
        - stdout: '{10.0.0.3: {10.0.0.2: 0}}'
        - stdout: '{10.0.0.6: {10.0.0.2: 0}}'
```

Create a list of grouped keys

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        l1: "{{ p.results|
                map(attribute='stdout')|
                map('from_yaml')|
                map('dict2items')|
                flatten|
                groupby('key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
l1:
  - - 10.0.0.3
    - - key: 10.0.0.3
        value:
          10.0.0.1: 2
      - key: 10.0.0.3
        value:
          10.0.0.2: 0
  - - 10.0.0.6
    - - key: 10.0.0.6
        value:
          10.0.0.1: 2
      - key: 10.0.0.6
        value:
          10.0.0.2: 0
```

Now, combine the dictionary

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        d1: "{{ d1|d({})|combine({_key: _val}) }}"
      loop: "{{ l1 }}"
      vars:
        _key: "{{ item.0 }}"
        _val: "{{ item.1|map(attribute='value')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
d1:
  10.0.0.3:
    - 10.0.0.1: 2
    - 10.0.0.2: 0
  10.0.0.6:
    - 10.0.0.1: 2
    - 10.0.0.2: 0
```

---

Combine the value items if you want to get dictionaries instead of the lists

```yaml
        _val: "{{ item.1|map(attribute='value')|combine }}"
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  d1:
    10.0.0.3:
      10.0.0.1: 2
      10.0.0.2: 0
    10.0.0.6:
      10.0.0.1: 2
      10.0.0.2: 0
```

Comment: as far as I know, dash indicates the start of a list item. then how to remove the dash on 10.0.0.2? so that d1 will be a list of two items (10.0.0.3 and 10.0.0.6), where each item is a dictionary containing two key-value pairs

Comment: Combine the items. I added the example.

Comment: Perhaps there's a syntax problem? because it gives me an error `FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ item.1|map(attribute='value')|combine }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleFilterError'>, original message: |combine expects dictionaries, got <generator object do_map at 0x7f019a1a4c80>"}`

Comment: The [combination of the dictionaries in a list](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L321) was added only recently. Update Ansible. Otherwise, you'll have to combine the dictionaries in a loop.

Comment: can i ask what version, exactly?

Comment: It was [merged to  2.9](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/57894)